# Diplay different <li> border size on tablet

Tags: html-lists, tablet

I have an issue related to css viewing of webview on Android 4.0.4

I have an list : using `<ul> , <li>` tags.
But when show on tablet 7 inches, some `<li>` has a different border size (> 1px).

Here is html :

```
<div id="cmSettingMenuList">
<ul>
            <li >11111111</li>
                <li >2222222</li>
                <li >33333333</li>
                 <li >11111111</li>
                <li >2222222</li>
                <li >33333333</li>
                 <li >11111111</li>
                <li >2222222</li>

                 <li >11111111</li>
                <li >2222222</li>
                <li >33333333</li>
                <li >33333333</li>
                 <li >11111111</li>
                <li >2222222</li>
                <li >33333333</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

I use 1 css for it:

```
#cmSettingMenuList ul {
width: 580px;
list-style: none;
overflow: visible;
}

#cmSettingMenuList ul li {
padding-left: 2px;
height: 58px;
line-height: 58px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #9AB2E7;
background-size: 26px;
position: relative;
}
```

Here is display on tablet:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBsBL.png

It's not same size.
Do you have any solution for it.

THANKS